# How to show total number of notification on top of my notification icon using GCM

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I am creating an android app where when GCM sends a message to my application then I want to show the total new notifications number. I want it to appear on top of my notification icon like facebook or Myntra(all the updates). My notification icon is in a tablayout. So how can I change or make a marker(or anything) just to show that there are new notification?

Comment: you will have to increment the number (hint use SharedPref. for getting the previous message count) of that particular Notification ID. And once user click on that notification. clear the notification count (SharedPref.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try following,

```
public class BadgeNumberExample extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_badge_number_example);
        setBadge(this,5);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.badge_number_example, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public static void setBadge(Context context, int count) {
        String launcherClassName = getLauncherClassName(context);
        if (launcherClassName == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE");
        intent.putExtra("badge_count", count);
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_package_name", context.getPackageName());
        intent.putExtra("badge_count_class_name", launcherClassName);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public static String getLauncherClassName(Context context) {

        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolveInfos) {
            String pkgName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            if (pkgName.equalsIgnoreCase(context.getPackageName())) {
                String className = resolveInfo.activityInfo.name;
                return className;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how are you accesing this from gcm i mean are you using service or what, can you please show gcm code for using this ??